# Problem with an analogy (Cell Membrane)

Tags: homework, cell-membrane, definitions

I'm studying biology for the first time seriously. I've been reading OpenStax College's material. 
In the section of "[The Cell Membrane](https://learn.saylor.org/mod/url/view.php?id=10810)", I have the following problem:

Choose the answer that best completes the following analogy: Diffusion is to ________ as endocytosis is to ________.

1. filtration; phagocytosis
2. osmosis; pinocytosis
3. solutes; fluid
4. gradient; chemical energy

I chose number 1, but the site says the correct answer is number 2. Could someone please explain why?

---

[EDIT]

I chose number 1, because diffusion and filtration were passive ways to transport, while endocytosis and phagocytosis are active. I didn't not take in to account that 2. fitted better, because the osmosis part was confusing me.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has 5 upvotes. This is a homework question with no attempt at working out an answer.

Comment: @James, sorry I thought of writing something else, but since this was an analogy I didn't know what else to put. Is it necessary to delete this?

Comment: Why was the answer to this question moved to the comments?

Comment: @AnaGalois It sounds like your question is actually about osmosis rather than anything else. If you are confused about osmosis, then ask a question specifically about whatever is confusing you about osmosis. This sort of MCQ format isn't a good for SE. See [this meta discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Osmosis is the diffusion of water.  Pinocytosis is the endocytosis of liquid/water.

Comment: While your answer is undoubtedly the one the question is looking for, [osmosis is *not* the simple diffusion of water](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.4722325).